# Spring Integration: Preserving ordering in an Aggregator

Tags: spring, spring-integration

Right now I have a use case where I have a stream of events coming in. There are a few splitters and then finally downstream an aggregator. As the stream is never ending and with the number of splitters we are unable to calculate the total number of messages we expect. However we are using a simple SpeL release strategy expression :

```
<release-strategy-expression="size() == 10"/>
```

We are using a `group-timeout` and also have set `send-partial-result-on-expiry=true`.

Given this use-case am I right in concluding that there is no in-built way to preserve the original ordering of the stream of events ?

I have tried using a `SequenceSizeReleaseStrategy` with `releasePartialSequences` set to true.

What I've observed is that this is sending each message as a separate group as it relies on the *group-size* header which is defaulted to zero.

Am I missing out on anything ? Is there a way to preserve the ordering in the aggregator given this use-case ?

Answer (score 1):

For that purpose there is an EI pattern `resequencer`: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.3.0.M4/reference/html/message-routing.html#resequencer.

So, you place it just before an aggregator and when that aggregator releases a group, messages are going to be in the result list in the sequence order.

The resequencer also can release partial groups if all the gaps in sequence are fulfilled.